# Changing time of schedule task

Tags: scheduled-apex, scheduled

I have a schedule task configured in force.com.
I want to change the time it runs. I go to set up / monitoring / schedule jobs. But I only see the option to delete it.

Is there any to make a change to time and save?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot reschedule existing scheduled jobs, you have to delete the existing one and recreate a new one with the new frequency.

Here is an [Idea for making scheduled jobs editable](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000H11Q).

You can schedule a new job by navigating to

> Setup > Develop > Apex Classes

and then click the Schedule Apex button. Alternatively you can also schedule via Anonymous Apex using [System.Schedule](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_system.htm)